# Android -Kaltura SDK integration

Tags: android, kaltura

I have downloaded Kaltura SDK and integrated into my project, I got below error, but when I ran demo application, I could run it.

```
    Error:Execution failed for task ':playerSDK:transformNative_libsWithSyncJniLibsForRelease'.
> java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/aaaa/AndroidWorkplace/MediaShare/playerSDK/build/intermediates/bundles/release/jni/lib/armeabi/libHLSPlayerSDK.so (No such file or directory)
```

This is my gradle file:

```
 buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.aaaa.testSample"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "0.1"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
    }


}


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile project(':playerSDK')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'

    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.0'

    compile ('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.5'){
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', module: 'httpclient'
    }

    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.5@11sd') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile files('libs/gson-2.2.4.jar')

}
```

Any support on this?

Comment: As I wrote in your bug report https://github.com/kaltura/player-sdk-native-android/issues/90, this is fixed in the latest version (current master).

Comment: @noamtm  i know it's late to comment on this thread. i have just started using kaltura sdk and it just bewilders me .It provides kaltura configurations and Kalturaclient class wh9ic uses asynctask evry now and then.. i mean multithreading is kept on countryside while making library.. i want to know how to use kaltura using retrofit and other libraries.Please share your valuable experience whith kaltura develpoment